# Is there a difference between the FUSE mount option "uid", and the bindfs-specific option "force-user"?

Tags: fuse

https://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs.1.html

> `-u, --force-user, -o force-user=...`
>
> Makes all files owned by the specified user. Also causes chown on the mounted filesystem to always fail.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.fuse.8.html

> `uid=N`  Override the st_uid field set by the filesystem (N is
>                 numeric).

Answer (score 1):

`uid=N` is not very user-friendly.  Normally people want to specify the *name* of the user, which is supported by `force-user`.

I'm not sure this is the answer.  For other filesystems like `vfat`, the `uid` mount option is automatically resolved from a name to a number by the `mount` command.  Maybe when it runs a separate helper like `mount.fuse`, the mount options are passed directly and the user name is not looked up, but I don't know.

Though I also wonder if the FUSE manpage is written incorrectly and `uid=sourcejedi` works  *as a mount option*, but it wouldn't work if you run the `bindfs` command directly with `-o uid=sourcejedi`.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that uid=N only works with the uid number not the uid= probably newer version may have some ways to defined fuse.

Comment: which command(s) did you use? `mount`, `mount.fuse`, `bindfs`, ... ?